# Application defined or object-defined error mergedcells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that either takes an ActiveCell and `MsgBox`es its `MergeArea` borders (works fine), or takes a predetermined range and does the same (fails). When I try the latter I get `application defined or object-defined` error.

```
Sub test2()
     Dim Titles As Range
     Set Titles = Range("E13:H13")

     Dim titlesMerge As Range
  '  Set titlesMerge = ActiveCell.MergeArea   'this works fine
     Set titlesMerge = Titles.MergeArea  'when use Range("E13:H13") it 
                              'fails

     MsgBox (titlesMerge.Row & " and " & titlesMerge.Rows.Count)
End Sub
```

Cells `"E13:H13"` are merged.

What is wrong here?

Comment: The MergeArea property only works on a single-cell range. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822300.aspx

Comment: So that explains why `.MergeArea` works with `ActiveCell` and not with `Selection` even though they refer to the same merged cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my curiosity about Sir [Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout)'s comment, I experimented with this code.

```
Sub caller()
Dim rMergedCell As Range
' Let B3:C4 a merged cell
Set rMergedCell = Range("B3:C4")

  Dim rTitlesCell As Range
  Set rTitlesCell = rMergedCell.Cells(1, 1).MergeArea

  MsgBox rTitlesCell.Row & " and " & rTitlesCell.Rows.Count
' Returns 3 and 2
End Sub
```

He remarked that the `MergeArea` property only works on a single-cell reference. So why not get the most-upper-left cell of the Merged cell? Hope this helps the OP.